# Compiz : unusually high CPU usage on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: compiz

Since yesterday, after last system upgrade, compiz CPU usage has gone wild :

```
horacio@horacio-xps13:~$ top

top - 15:09:10 up  3:31,  2 users,  load average: 2,62, 2,75, 2,59
Tasks: 261 total,   2 running, 259 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 50,1 us,  4,6 sy,  0,0 ni, 45,1 id,  0,2 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:   7731228 total,  6252616 used,  1478612 free,   239548 buffers
KiB Swap: 15871996 total,        0 used, 15871996 free,  1451684 cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                       
 2394 horacio   20   0 1929m 407m  44m S 126,3  5,4  80:07.62 compiz                                                                                                        
 5908 horacio   20   0 3242m 2,1g  59m S  60,2 28,6  30:27.73 firefox                                                                                                       
 1163 root      20   0  697m 433m  72m S  25,3  5,7  14:48.66 Xorg                                                                                                          
 6017 horacio   20   0  905m 263m  34m S   4,0  3,5   2:07.85 plugin-containe                                                                                               
 6669 horacio   20   0  707m  20m  13m S   3,0  0,3   0:01.31 gnome-terminal                                                                                                
 6989 horacio   20   0 24876 1708 1128 R   0,7  0,0   0:00.05 top                                                                                                           
 2374 horacio   20   0 20236  940  768 S   0,3  0,0   0:05.01 syndaemon
```

That while doing nothing besides Firefox, if I open other programs it goes worse. The fun works without stop, it is definitively not normal.

When I start a Lubuntu session (no compiz), I have no problem.

Any idea? Any suggestion? Please?

Using Ubuntu 13.10 on a Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition, with an Intel graphics card.

This is the result of lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QS77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6235 (rev 24)
```

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work for some people. Maybe it will work for you too.

1. Open CompizConfig Settings Manager.
2. Go to *OpenGL*.
3. Turn off *Wait for Vsync*.

That's it.

*Source: [Is Compiz Consuming Too much CPU? Here’s The Solution!](https://web.archive.org/web/20150213185352/http://followthegeeks.com/compiz-is-consuming-too-much-cpu-heres-the-solution/)*